# jquery, XML to HTML

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I have a question , about parsing xml.

I want to get some xml data to HTML, but I have a problem, I can get this data just from local xml, when I try to get data from external URL it doesn't work, for example from

http://www.w3schools.com/XML/plant_catalog.xml

This is jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://www.w3schools.com/XML/plant_catalog.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('CATALOG').each(function(){
                        var title = $(this).find('BOTANICAL').text();
                        var url = $(this).find('BOTANICAL').text();
                        $('<div class="items" id="link_"></div>').html('<a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a>').appendTo('#page-wrap');

                    });
                }
            });
        });
     </script>
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
        <h1>Reading XML with jQuery</h1>
     </div>
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You cannot request files from different domains for security reasons..

quoting http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> When data is retrieved from remote servers (**which is only possible using the script or jsonp data types**)

Comment: It means, that I can not use this kind of url , I have to use something like " url: "../site.xml"
?

Comment: yes, only urls local to your domain. It could be relative Urls inside your domain like url: '/somepath/somefile.xml'. Relative urls (starting with /) start from the domain root instead of the current folder

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a local file on your server as a wrapper to avoid these cross domain problems.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "catalog.php",
...
```

local catalog.php

```
<?php 
  header("Content-Type: text/xml");  
  echo file_get_contents("http://www.w3schools.com/XML/plant_catalog.xml"); 
?>
```

Notice that your server must have `url fopen` enabled for this to work.